# Text to Rows VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet with about a good 4000 rows of data, one of the columns of data has unique order numbers that I want separated using "/" as my delimiter. So essentially I want:

```
Name      Order#       Date
Jane      123/001/111  08/15/2013
Gary      333/121      09/01/2013
Jack      222          09/02/2013
```

To look like this:

```
Name      Order#       Date
Jane      123          08/15/2013
Jane      001          08/15/2013
Jane      111          08/15/2013
Gary      333          09/01/2013
Gary      121          09/01/2013
Jack      222          09/02/2013
```

I am fairly new to VBA, so I decided to try to Google for a solution where I came upon this nice bit of code.

```
        Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean) 
    Dim ans 
    Dim Cels As Long, i As Long 
    Cancel = True 
    ans = Split(Target, ":") 
    Cels = UBound(ans) 
    Target.Offset(1).Resize(Cels).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown 
    Rows(Target.Row).Copy Cells(Target.Row + 1, "A").Resize(Cels) 
    For i = 0 To Cels 
        Target.Offset(i) = ans(i) 
    Next 
End Sub
```

It works great but the way this macro functions is that you have to double click the row to separate the values. What I was hoping for is a way to pass this function through a For loop so it executes throughout the entire spreadsheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you sheet looks sort of like this

[image]

then

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()

    Columns("B:B").NumberFormat = "@"
    Dim i As Long, c As Long, r As Range, v As Variant

    For i = 1 To Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        v = Split(Range("B" & i), "/")
        c = c + UBound(v) + 1
    Next i

    For i = 2 To c
        Set r = Range("B" & i)
        Dim arr As Variant
        arr = Split(r, "/")
        Dim j As Long
        r = arr(0)
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
            Rows(r.Row + j & ":" & r.Row + j).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            r.Offset(j, 0) = arr(j)
            r.Offset(j, -1) = r.Offset(0, -1)
            r.Offset(j, 1) = r.Offset(0, 1)
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

will produce

[image]

Comment: That works beautifully, thank you sir. I do have one question. The example I posted was a sample but my actual entries have about 10 columns. I noticed in your code that it pasted the entries to the left and right of the Order# in the For loop going through the array. Is there a way to just have it copy the entire row, or do I have to manually put in each column.

Comment: Hi @KevinMalloy. There are two ways of achieving what you want. First would be to insert X amount of rows, and then copy and paste the rows and work with the strings in between the slashes. The other way (the one I chose based on your description) is to work with the slashes - work out how many lines you need to insert - and then copy all the columns using the offset. The code may not look very pretty (depending on the amount of columns you have) but it would have done the job. So If you have about 10 columns it's still worth just adding the *lefts* and *rights*. Hope this helps

Comment: @KevinMalloy bear in mind that you could automate copying of the columns with a simple for loop and using Cells(x, y) instead of Range. If you are going for that approach and not sure how to do it, it would be worth asking another question as any modifications to your current question would invalidate my current answer :(

Comment: I was thinking the same general idea, thank you for your answers, it is very much appreciated. I think for now I'll just add the columns in now and at a later point make that loop to clean it up.