# Text to rows in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with tweets database. The problem I'm trying to solve is splitting hashtags by sign'#'. So, that's what I have:

idTweet RT text hashtags

111     ... ... yyc#yycflood#alberta

And that's what I'm trying to get

idTweet RT text hashtags

111     ... ... yyc

111     ... ... yycflood

111     ... ... alberta

There is more than 30 columns (the last one is BJ).

Actually similar problem was discussed here: [Text to Rows VBA Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19815321/text-to-rows-vba-excel). But in my case number of signs '#' can reach 13. I was trying to do this in python in openpyxl module, but probably I'm not so familiar with its syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the `Split` function.  It takes a string and returns a `String` array based on the delimiter you specify.  You can read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278528(v=office.14).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, UBound(Split(ActiveCell.Value, "#")))).Value = Split(ActiveCell.Value, "#")
```