# Split a CSV field into different rows in SQL

Tags: sql, csv

A colleague of mines encountered this problem while working on a COBOL program and eventually solved it at the application level.
Still I am curious if it is possible to solve it on the data access level, with SQL.
This is somehow related to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29039410/can-i-use-sql-to-split-contents-of-a-table-column-stored-as-csv-comma-seperated), but I'd like to use only ANSI SQL.

I'm looking for a single SQL select query that acts on a VARCHAR field that contains variable length CSV rows. The purpose of the query is to split every CSV field in its own result set row.

Here is an example with schema and data (and here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20a9b)):

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (`field` varchar(100));

 INSERT INTO table1 (`field`)
      VALUES
             ('Hello,world,!')    ,
             ('Haloa,!')          ,
             ('Have,a,nice,day,!');
```

Here is the output I'd like to have from the query:

```
Hello
world
!
Haloa
!
Have
a
nice
day
!
```

The CSV separator used is the comma, and for now I wouldn't worry about escaping.

Comment: Depends on your DBMS. There are some implementation of a split function (much like in many languages) and you would need to invoke if for each table record (field) with `,` as separator. If not available in your DBMS, you can write a simple function that would return a simple array/cursor/result set.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: Not storing comma-separated values into an SQL table in the first place prevents many headaches. You seem to have control over the database - design it properly instead of wasting your time with the creation of workarounds for completely avoidable problems.

Comment: @FDavidov as I mentioned, my colleague already resolved it at application level (aka creating a function/subroutine)

Comment: @jarh I explicitely asked for an ANSI SQL solution, if it exists

Comment: @Tomalak you couldn't be more right, but no, I don't have any control over the database, that is a 30 years old bank database. In these kind of systems it happens that poor design choices have layered over the years. Replacing it with a more proper table design would cost too much and nobody wants to be responsible for that much of an effort, therefor you can just go along with it.

Comment: Your sample SQL is non-standard to begin with. An ANSI solution would be to use `unnest()` but I don't know any ANSI feature that would allow turning a CSV string into an array (which `unnest()` requires). Plus only one DBMS I know supports `unnest()`

Comment: Yes, ANSI SQL, I got it from the beginning. The issue is that you don't have any up-front clue on the number of sub-elements you may have within a string (in your example, you have 5 in the last string, but you could have 500 or more). So, the solutions would be either a recursive query (Oracle supports this but I don't know about other DBMSs) or to write a simple piece of code (much simpler than the query suggested by massko).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I didn't know about the unnest() function, is that ANSI? I'm sorry the snippet isn't ANSI in the first place, I wrote it just to give a fiddle to play with.

Comment: Yes, `unnest()` is ANSI SQL and will turn an array in a list of rows. The question is: how to turn a CSV string into an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is ANSI SQL:

```
with recursive word_list (field, word, rest, field_id, level) as (             
  select field, 
         substring(field from 1 for position(',' in field) - 1) as word,
         substring(field from position(',' in field) + 1) as rest,
         row_number() over () as field_id,
         1
  from table1
  union all 
  select c.field, 
         case 
            when position(',' in p.rest) = 0 then p.rest
            else substring(p.rest from 1 for position(',' in p.rest) - 1) 
         end as word,
         case 
            when position(',' in p.rest) = 0 then null
            else substring(p.rest from position(',' in p.rest) + 1) 
         end as rest, 
         p.field_id,
         p.level + 1
  from table1 as c
    join word_list p on c.field = p.field and position(',' in p.rest) >= 0
) 
select word
from word_list
order by field_id, level;
```

This assumes that the values in `field` are unique.

Here is a [running example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4e0f0ef5dad399e02eba007d6f3439dc)

Comment: this is amazing, here is an overview of the databases in which this could work: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#Common_table_expression

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you could use something like that (maybe it's not the most elegant but it gives the result you want) - simply replace `tab` with **your_table_name**:

```
WITH 
tab2 AS (
SELECT t.field,
       CASE WHEN INSTR(t.field, ',', 1, 1) > 0 AND regexp_count(t.field,',') >= 1 THEN INSTR(t.field, ',', 1, 1) ELSE NULL END AS pos1,
       CASE WHEN INSTR(t.field, ',', 1, 2) > 0 AND regexp_count(t.field,',') >= 2 THEN INSTR(t.field, ',', 1, 2) ELSE NULL END AS pos2,
       CASE WHEN INSTR(t.field, ',', 1, 3) > 0 AND regexp_count(t.field,',') >= 3 THEN INSTR(t.field, ',', 1, 3) ELSE NULL END AS pos3,
       CASE WHEN INSTR(t.field, ',', 1, 4) > 0 AND regexp_count(t.field,',') >= 4 THEN INSTR(t.field, ',', 1, 4) ELSE NULL END AS pos4,
       CASE WHEN INSTR(t.field, ',', 1, 5) > 0 AND regexp_count(t.field,',') >= 5 THEN INSTR(t.field, ',', 1, 5) ELSE NULL END AS pos5,
       CASE WHEN INSTR(t.field, ',', 1, 6) > 0 AND regexp_count(t.field,',') >= 6 THEN INSTR(t.field, ',', 1, 6) ELSE NULL END AS pos6
FROM tab t
),
tab3 AS (
SELECT SUBSTR(tt.field,1,tt.pos1-1) AS col1,
       SUBSTR(tt.field,tt.pos1+1, CASE WHEN tt.pos2 IS NULL THEN LENGTH(tt.field) - tt.pos1 ELSE tt.pos2 - tt.pos1 - 1 END) AS col2,
       SUBSTR(tt.field,tt.pos2+1, CASE WHEN tt.pos3 IS NULL THEN LENGTH(tt.field) - tt.pos2 ELSE tt.pos3 - tt.pos2 - 1 END) AS col3,
       SUBSTR(tt.field,tt.pos3+1, CASE WHEN tt.pos4 IS NULL THEN LENGTH(tt.field) - tt.pos3 ELSE tt.pos4 - tt.pos3 - 1 END) AS col4,
       SUBSTR(tt.field,tt.pos4+1, CASE WHEN tt.pos5 IS NULL THEN LENGTH(tt.field) - tt.pos4 ELSE tt.pos5 - tt.pos4 - 1 END) AS col5,
       SUBSTR(tt.field,tt.pos5+1, CASE WHEN tt.pos6 IS NULL THEN LENGTH(tt.field) - tt.pos5 ELSE tt.pos6 - tt.pos5 - 1 END) AS col6
       ,ROWNUM AS r
FROM tab2 tt
),
tab4 AS (
SELECT ttt.col1 AS col FROM tab3 ttt WHERE r  = 1
UNION ALL SELECT ttt.col2 FROM tab3 ttt WHERE r  = 1
UNION ALL SELECT ttt.col3 FROM tab3 ttt WHERE r  = 1
UNION ALL SELECT ttt.col4 FROM tab3 ttt WHERE r  = 1
UNION ALL SELECT ttt.col5 FROM tab3 ttt WHERE r  = 1
UNION ALL SELECT ttt.col6 FROM tab3 ttt WHERE r  = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT ttt.col1 FROM tab3 ttt WHERE r  = 2
UNION ALL SELECT ttt.col2 FROM tab3 ttt WHERE r  = 2
UNION ALL SELECT ttt.col3 FROM tab3 ttt WHERE r  = 2
UNION ALL SELECT ttt.col4 FROM tab3 ttt WHERE r  = 2
UNION ALL SELECT ttt.col5 FROM tab3 ttt WHERE r  = 2
UNION ALL SELECT ttt.col6 FROM tab3 ttt WHERE r  = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT ttt.col1 FROM tab3 ttt WHERE r  = 3
UNION ALL SELECT ttt.col2 FROM tab3 ttt WHERE r  = 3
UNION ALL SELECT ttt.col3 FROM tab3 ttt WHERE r  = 3
UNION ALL SELECT ttt.col4 FROM tab3 ttt WHERE r  = 3
UNION ALL SELECT ttt.col5 FROM tab3 ttt WHERE r  = 3
UNION ALL SELECT ttt.col6 FROM tab3 ttt WHERE r  = 3
UNION ALL
SELECT ttt.col1 FROM tab3 ttt WHERE r  = 4
UNION ALL SELECT ttt.col2 FROM tab3 ttt WHERE r  = 4
UNION ALL SELECT ttt.col3 FROM tab3 ttt WHERE r  = 4
UNION ALL SELECT ttt.col4 FROM tab3 ttt WHERE r  = 4
UNION ALL SELECT ttt.col5 FROM tab3 ttt WHERE r  = 4
UNION ALL SELECT ttt.col6 FROM tab3 ttt WHERE r  = 4
UNION ALL
SELECT ttt.col1 FROM tab3 ttt WHERE r  = 5
UNION ALL SELECT ttt.col2 FROM tab3 ttt WHERE r  = 5
UNION ALL SELECT ttt.col3 FROM tab3 ttt WHERE r  = 5
UNION ALL SELECT ttt.col4 FROM tab3 ttt WHERE r  = 5
UNION ALL SELECT ttt.col5 FROM tab3 ttt WHERE r  = 5
UNION ALL SELECT ttt.col6 FROM tab3 ttt WHERE r  = 5
)
SELECT col
FROM tab4
WHERE col IS NOT NULL
```

it gives me the result:

```
1   Hello
2   world
3   !
4   Haloa
5   !
6   Have
7   a
8   nice
9   day
10  !
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, here's another Oracle specific method.  Maybe it will give an idea or help a future searcher at least.

```
SQL> with tbl(rownbr, col1) as (
           select 1, 'Hello,world,!'     from dual union
           select 2, 'Haloa,!'           from dual union
           select 3, 'Have,a,nice,day,!' from dual
      )
   SELECT rownbr, column_value substring_nbr,
        regexp_substr(col1, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, column_value, null, 1)
    FROM tbl,
                TABLE(
                  CAST(
                    MULTISET(SELECT LEVEL
                                FROM dual
                                CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(col1, ',')+1
                            ) AS sys.OdciNumberList
                  )
                )
      order by rownbr, substring_nbr;

    ROWNBR SUBSTRING_NBR REGEXP_SUBSTR(COL
---------- ------------- -----------------
         1             1 Hello
         1             2 world
         1             3 !
         2             1 Haloa
         2             2 !
         3             1 Have
         3             2 a
         3             3 nice
         3             4 day
         3             5 !

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```